# Lists doubled in size

Tags: python, list, statsmodels

I am trying to store statsmodel.ols rsquared and rsquared_adj values for each column in a couple of different lists so I can later create a new dataframe with the column name, score and adjusted score for each column on its own. The data I am using is a dataframe with 238 columns (I want to individually test 231 of them, ie. for each column test the r2 score for that column on its own).

When I store statsmodel.ols.rsquared (and rsquared_adj and a column name) in a list and iterate through all of the columns I want to test, I end up with 462 values in the list. I was only expecting half that number.

I am still just learning how to use python to analyse data so my code is probably very inneficient but I have included it below so hopefully someone can explain where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me understand why my code is doing this.

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import random
import openpyxl as op

#timing start the clock
start = time.time()

#Create empty lists
score_adj = []
score = []
col_name = []

#Assign variables
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path = dirname + "/iteration1/"
r = random.randint(1,1000)

infile, X_col, y_col = ('test_summary_with_weather_columns', 
np.arange(7,238), 3)

#create df
for x in range (1,3):
    filename = path + infile + str(x) + '.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    dfr = df.iloc[:,X_col]

#Assign X & y
    X = df.iloc[:, X_col].values
    y = df.iloc[:, y_col].values
    first_X_column = X_col[0]

#import library and prepare df 
    import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
    numRows = df.shape[0]
    X = np.append(arr = np.ones((numRows, 1)).astype(int), values = X, axis 
= 1)

# Split into training and test set
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 
0.2, random_state=r)

#Assign X_col
    for xc in range (1,232):
        X_train_single = X_train[:, xc]

##fit regressor
        regressor_ols = sm.OLS(endog = y_train, exog = X_train_single).fit()

#Assign values to lists
        score_adj.append(regressor_ols.rsquared_adj)
        score.append(regressor_ols.rsquared)
        col_name.append(dfr.columns[xc-1])
```

Comment: You have two nested loops: One for `x` from 1 to 2, then one for `xc` from 1 to 231. In each iteration of the inner loop you append one item to `score`. That's 462 items. Why do you expect there to be only 231 items in `score`?

Comment: Ah thank you. For each x I want to start a new list altogether. That definitely explains it. Thank you.